# Server gives different response from iOS/Restkit than from curl

Tags: restkit

I'm having trouble with my iOS/Restkit app. It used to work fine but now no longer does. And of course, I've chaged a million things, but nothing that I think would be significant. The problem is that I can communicate with my server just fine from the terminal with curl, but when I try from my app my server throws an exception! What am I doing wrong with RestKit?

First we see I've deleted my account and created a new one from Terminal. (I also went and deleted it again just so I can try and create it from my app.) (IP addresses are removed.)

```
$ curl "http://0.0.0.0:8080/registration/rest/users/delete_account" -d "email=paul%40longpointlabs.com&pwd=123456&uname=Paul" 
Success 
$ curl "http://0.0.0.0:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account" -d "email=paul%40longpointlabs.com&pwd=123456&uname=Paul" 
6345b3cedc5935b1dad9863c795c26391326998921644
$ curl "http://0.0.0.0:8080/registration/rest/users/delete_account" -d "email=paul%40longpointlabs.com&pwd=123456&uname=Paul" 
Success
```

That all went as expected. So here's my app's code:

```
{
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    [CreateAccount setupCreateAccountMapping];

    CreateAccount* user = [[CreateAccount alloc] init];
    user.email = @"paul@longpointlabs.com";
    user.uname = @"Paul";
    user.pwd = @"123456";

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user delegate:self];
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error 
{    
    RKResponse *response = [objectLoader response]; 
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError Code: %d", [response statusCode] );
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError Body: %@", [response bodyAsString] );

}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response 
{
    NSLog(@"idLoadResponse: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
}
```

And when I run this I get this response. First, from the tracing: (I've removed the IP address...)

```
2012-01-19 14:04:10.244 test[2703:fb03] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://0.0.0.0:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Length" = 64;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}. HTTP Body: {"pwd":"123456","uname":"Paul","email":"paul@longpointlabs.com"}.
2012-01-19 14:04:10.345 test[2703:fb03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 406
2012-01-19 14:04:10.345 test[2703:fb03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 79;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 19 Jan 2012 19:04:10 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
}
2012-01-19 14:04:10.346 test[2703:fb03] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16053 Could not commit transaction.
```

And then my didLoadResponse:

```
2012-01-19 14:07:22.850 test[2750:fb03] didLoadResponse: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16053 Could not commit transaction.
```

And then, curiously, didFailWithError is also called:

```
2012-01-19 14:08:23.188 test[2750:fb03] didFailWithError Code: 406
2012-01-19 14:08:35.250 test[2750:fb03] didFailWithError Body: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16053 Could not commit transaction.
```

I'm baffled at this, how can my iOS app get a different response back from curl? I have control of the server so I don't think it is responding to the User-Agent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have RestKit configured to POST JSON, but you're using curl to POST form-encoded params. You need to change your RestKit serialization MIME type.

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks!

    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;

I had worked in that section of code awhile back for some other part of my app... forgot about the change.